# PHP - counting in a single variable the difference in operations between two values of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, operators, addition

My problem is when I count the "wins" of a player , it counts every wins in the previous value and the current one.

More detailed , I have this values

```
$a0 = 10;
$a1 = 12;
$a2 = 14;

$b0 = 20;
$b1 = 20; 
$b2 = 10;

$arr1 = array($a0, $a1, $a2);  // Martina's numbers 
$arr2 = array($b0, $b1, $b2);  // George's numbers


foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){

        if($val > $arr2[$key]){  // Martina win , +1 point  for Martina

            $martina++;
            print($martina . " ");

        }elseif($val < $arr2[$key]){   // George win , +1 point for George
            $george++;
            print($george . " "); 

        }else{  // if is Equal - no score increase 

            print("");

        } 

}
```

The score between them it must to be 1  2 for George in this case , but my code outputs also the score from first win , and the additioned score.

How can I make it to trow me only the additioned score.. ?

Hope that you understand my explanation of the problem , I'm at beginning on this language.

Comment: move `prints` outside of `foreach`

Comment: hehe: "+1 point for Martina", _adds a point to Alice_. "+1 point for George", _adds a point to Bob_ xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move prints outside of `foreach`

```
$arr1 = array(10, 12, 14);  // Martina's numbers 
$arr2 = array(20, 20, 10);  // George's numbers
$alice = 0;
$bob = 0;

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    if($val > $arr2[$key]) {
        // Martina win , +1 point  for Martina
        $alice++;
    } elseif($val < $arr2[$key]) {
        // George win , +1 point for George
        $bob++;
    } 

}

print('Alice: ' . $alice . PHP_EOL);
print('Bob: ' . $bob . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Good , this works , but If 2 of 3 values or one of 3 values of the arrays are EQUAL , How can I make it works , counting me the winner point for that one who has the number greater... and the equal to be caunted as nothing / or +0...? ...here is a problem too..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it !!

Thank you very much   E_p  for your help to solving this problem.
**The final and the right code is :**

```
<?php

// Values of Martina's numbers

$a0 = 21;
$a1 = 2;
$a2 = 32;

//Values of George's numbers
$b0 = 22; 
$b1 = 3;  
$b2 = 13; 

//Putting the values into arrays
$arr1 = array($a0, $a1, $a2);
$arr2 = array($b0, $b1, $b2);

// Given two variables for players score
$martina = 0;
$george = 0;


foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){

            if($val > $arr2[$key]){
                $martina++;
            }elseif($val < $arr2[$key]){
                $george++;
            }

}

print($martina . " " . $george . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Lines: `$george;` `$martina;` are useless as they do nothing. As for `echo "Insert the right values!";` Not sure how would you ever get there.

Comment: Now it matches my answer almost 100%. Why don't  you just accept my answer?